# Why Glassfish 3.1 on CentOs 6 can't serve port 80?

Tags: java, centos, glassfish, glassfish-3, centos6

I have set my firewall setting for port 80, 8080, 4848.
If on Glassfish I active listener for 80 it can't start and throws an error:

```
 Permission denied: 80=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services...
```

Comment: Have you checked that no other process is already running on port 80? Check with `lsof -i :80`.

Comment: yes, but nothing occupies 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ports 0 up to 1023 are called [well-known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports). Glassfish would have to be executed with root privileges in order to bind to this port.

Let Glassfish bind to 127.0.0.1:8080 or any other unprivileged port instead and use NGINX as a [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) to map incoming requests on port 80 to your Glassfish server.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/710253 describes a couple of ways to allow a non-root processes to bind on "well-known" ports.